# Building an IIF statement with a Yes/No Field

Tags: ms-access, if-statement

I'm trying to do a calculation to refer back to a field if another field `Yes` and I keep getting the `#Type!` error.

The fields are `[Written]` which contains a currency total, `[LR Test]` which is the `Yes` or `No` field and `[Written totals]`. So basically what I want my expression to do is `IF LR Test = Yes` I want `[Written Totals]` to show the amount from the `[Written]` field, IF it's a `No`, then it could be `Null` or `0`.

This is the calculation I have tried that returns with #Type!

```
IIf(([LR Test]=Yes),[Written],Null)
```

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated. I'm very new to access so it has been quite a struggle.

Comment: Instead of Yes, try True or "Yes".

Answer (score 3):

If your [LR Test] field is of the type "Yes/No", you can refer to it with True False.

```
IIf([LR Test]=True,[Written],Null)
```

This would also work, since Access stores a true value as a -1 under the covers

```
IIf([LR Test]=-1,[Written],Null)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes/No fields in MS Access are actually `Boolean` fields, as already mentioned by Josh in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29398981/6884).

So because `[LR Test]` is a boolean value by itself, you don't need to compare it to anything to get `Iif` to work.

This is enough:

```
IIf(([LR Test]),[Written],Null)
```